# Java account class program

Tags: java

I have wrote this program over and over again, can someone please tell me what I am missing, it looks like its a small error I am not catching.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

Design a class named Account that contains:

- A private int data field named id for the account(default 0)
- A private double data field named balance for the account (default 0)
- A private double data field named annualInterestRate that stores the
  current interest rate (default 0). Assume all accounts have the same
  interest rate.
- A private Date data field named dateCreated that stores the date when the account was created. A no-arg constructor that creates a default account.
- A constructor that creates an account
  with the specific id and initial balance.
- The accessor and mutator methods for id, balance, and annualInterestRate.
- The accessor method for dateCreated
- A method named getMonthlyInterestRate() that returns the monthly interest rate.
- A method named withdraw that withdraws a specified amount from the account A method named deposit that deposits a specified amount to the account.
- Write a test program that
  creates an Account object with an account ID of 1122, a balance of
  $20,000, and an annual interest rate of 4.5%. Use the withdraw method
  to withdraw $2,500, use the deposit method to deposit $3,000 and
  print the balanace, the monthly interest, and the date when this
  account was created.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Assign22 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Account account1 = new Account(1122, 20000, .045);
account1.withdraw(2500);
account1.deposit(3000);
System.out.println("Date Created:" + java.util.Date dateCreated = new java.util.Date());
System.out.println("Account ID:" + account1.id);
System.out.println("Balance:" + account1.getBalance());
System.out.println("Interest Rate:" + account1.getAnnualInterestRate());
System.out.println("Balance after withdraw of 2500:" +       account1.getAnnualInterestRate());
System.out.println("Balance after deposit of 3000:" + account1.getAnnualInterestRate());
System.out.println("Monthly Interest:" + account1.id);

System.out.println("Process completed.");
}

class Account {
//define variables
private int id;
private double balance; // balance for account
private double annualInterestRate; //stores the current interest rate
private Date dateCreated; //stores the date account created

//no arg construtor
Account () {
    id = 0;
    balance = 0.0;
    annualInterestRate = 0.0;
}
//constructor with specific id and initial balance
Account(int newId, double newBalance) {
    id = newId;
    balance = newBalance;
}
Account(int newId, double newBalance, double newAnnualInterestRate) {
    id = newId;
    balance = newBalance;
    annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
}
//accessor/mutator methods for id, balance, and annualInterestRate
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
    return annualInterestRate;
}
public void setId(int newId) {
    id = newId;
}
public void setBalance(double newBalance) {
    balance = newBalance;
}
public void setAnnualInterestRate(double newAnnualInterestRate) {
    annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
}
//accessor method for dateCreated
public void setDateCreated(Date newDateCreated) {
    dateCreated = newDateCreated;
}
//define method getMonthlyInterestRate
double getMonthlyInterestRate() {
    return annualInterestRate/12;
}
//define method withdraw
double withdraw(double amount) {
    return balance -= amount;
}   
//define method deposit
double deposit(double amount) {
    return balance += amount;   
}
}

}
```

**This is the error that I am receiving: Not sure what I missed here:**

"Syntax error on token "Date", , expected after this token dateCreated cannot be resolved to a variable at Assign22.main(Assign22.java:12)"

Answer (score 4):

You can't have variable declarations as part of `String` concatenation expressions

```
System.out.println("Date Created:" + java.util.Date dateCreated = new java.util.Date());
```

Split that up

```
java.util.Date dateCreated = new java.util.Date()
System.out.println("Date Created:" + dateCreated);
```